# How to disable ads profiling when using show_ads.js

Tags: javascript, adsense

I am using AdExchange for my ads and embeding show_ads.js script from google.

According to https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/7678538?hl=en this code fragment should disable ads profiling:

```
(adsbygoogle=window.adsbygoogle||[]).requestNonPersonalizedAds=1
```

But it does not work. After including `show_ads.js` `window.adsbygoogle` is undefined. I would appreciate any suggestions.